# How to read a multidimensional array from a .plist file in macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, path, plist

In a macOS project I have to read the contents of a .plist file and insert it into a multidimensional array. Not having found much material for macOS, I read tutorials and questions oriented to iOS programming.

I created a code that I thought could work, but when it comes to reading the contents of the file, it fails. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
 // Edited

 let filePath = documentDirectory + "/Docs/" + "MyFile" + ".plist"
 var resourceFileArray: NSArray?

 //load the content of the plist file
 if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: (filePath), ofType: "plist") {
     resourceFileArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path)
 }

 if let resourceFileArrayContent = resourceFileArray {
     print(resourceFileArrayContent)
 } else {
     print("error")     // it always falls here
 }
```

Content of the plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <array>
        <string>One</string>
        <string>false</string>
        <string></string>
        <string></string>
        <string>false</string>
        <string>false</string>
        <string>false</string>
    </array>
</array>
</plist>
```

Comment: 1. Why is the file type in reading the file set to nil?  2.  resourceFileDictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) is incomplete.

Comment: 3. Your plist shows an array of an array, not a dictionary unlike resourceFileDictionary.

Comment: @El Tomato, thank you for reporting the errors. I have updated the question.

Comment: Is the file in the documents folder or in the bundle? Your code is confusing. Apart from that use `PropertyListSerialization`, not the `NSArray / NSDictionary` API to read plist files. And if the file is a property list file, why is the file extension not `plist`?

Comment: @vadian, actually the file is in the documents folder not in the bundle. Thanks for your very useful comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get that plist content as **NSDictionary**, you can see from the plist content that it is of type **[[String]]**. You can use **PropertyListDecoder** for Swift 4 but since you are using Swift 3, you can use PropertyListSerialization like this,

```
do {
  let data = try Data(contentsOf: plistFileURL)
  let output = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data,
                                                       options: [],
                                                       format: nil) as! [[String]]

} catch {
  print("Error occurred: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```